# Python:Efficient way to check if dictionary is empty or not

Tags: python, dictionary

How to check if dictionary is empty or not? more specifically, my program starts with some key in dictionary and I have a loop which iterates till there are key in dictionary. Overall algo is like this:

> Start with some key in dict
>      while there is key in dict
>     do some operation on first key in dict
>     remove first key

Please note that `some operation` in above loop may add new keys to dictionary.
I've tried 
`for key,value in d.iteritems()`

but it is failing as during while loop some new key are added.

Comment: `if dict` should check for emptiness.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? What is the algorithm for, what's in the dict?

Comment: A normal dict is just a hashtable and has no concept of order, 'first' is meaningless.  You could use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead if you need this behaviour.

Answer (score 48):

`any(d)`

This will return true if the dict. d contains at least one truelike key,  false otherwise.

Example:

`any({0:'test'}) == False`

another (more general) way is to check the number of items:

`len(d)`

Comment: This is the proper solution according to http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Comment: This isn't right.  `any(d)` returns True if d contains at least one truelike key.  But if the keys are falselike -- for example, `d = {0: 'this dictionary is not empty'}` -- then `any(d)` will be False.

Comment: Thanks @DSM modified according to the falselike/truelike keys remark.

Answer (score 19):

Just check the dictionary:

```
d = {'hello':'world'}
if d:
  print 'not empty'
else:
  print 'empty'

d = {}
if d:
  print 'not empty'
else:
  print 'empty'
```

Answer (score 18):

I just wanted to know if the dictionary i was going to try to pull data from had data in it in the first place, this seems to be simplest way.

```
d = {}

bool(d)

#should return
False

d = {'hello':'world'}

bool(d)

#should return
True
```

Answer (score 15):

This will do it:

```
while d:
    k, v = d.popitem()
    # now use k and v ...
```

A dictionary in boolean context is False if empty, True otherwise.

There is no "first" item in a dictionary, because dictionaries aren't ordered. But popitem will remove and return *some* item for you each time.

Comment: Then how should I get first key in while loop?

Comment: actually main problem is when you add keys in inner operation then interpreter is throwing an error :dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: That's a different problem. don't modify the object you're iterating over.  What you need is a queue.

Comment: I've expanded my answer. While you can't modify an object you're iterating over, as @kreativitea says, and a queue is the right answer in some algorithms, a dictionary can be a fine choice when order doesn't matter.

Comment: @JameySharp. Hey I didn't meant to hurt you. Sorry if I did by mistake.

Comment: @RohitJain Apology accepted, we're cool. :-)

Answer (score 9):

I would say that way is more pythonic and fits on line:

If you need to check value only with the use of *your function*:

`if filter( your_function, dictionary.values() ): ...`

When you need to know if your dict contains any keys:

`if dictionary: ...`

Anyway, using loops here is not Python-way.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the for loop uses the *iter* function and you should not mess with a structure while iterating over it.

Does it have to be a dictionary? If you use a list something like this might work:

```
while len(my_list) > 0:
    #get last item from list
    key, value = my_list.pop()
    #do something with key and value
    #maybe
    my_list.append((key, value))
```

Note that my_list is a list of the tuple (key, value). The only disadvantage is that you cannot access by key.

EDIT: Nevermind, the answer above is mostly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it:

```
isempty = (dict1 and True) or False
```

if dict1 is empty then dict1 and True will give {} and this when resolved with False gives False.

if dict1 is non-empty then dict1 and True gives True and this resolved with False gives True

Comment: This is needlessly wordy. Try `bool(dict1)`.