# How to check if a dictionary is empty?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to check if a dictionary is empty but it doesn't behave properly. It just skips it and displays **ONLINE** without anything aside from the display the message. Any ideas why ?

```
def isEmpty(self, dictionary):
    for element in dictionary:
        if element:
            return True
        return False

def onMessage(self, socket, message):
    if self.isEmpty(self.users) == False:
        socket.send("Nobody is online, please use REGISTER command" \
                 " in order to register into the server")
    else:
        socket.send("ONLINE " + ' ' .join(self.users.keys()))
```

Comment: To check if `self.users` is nonempty, just do `if self.users`.

Comment: Your `isEmpty` actually returns `True` if the first key yielded from the dictionary is truey and returns `False` otherwise. If the dictionary is empty, it returns `None` which is not `== False`.

Comment: Your if statement is backwards.

Comment: be careful to false-like keys http://stackoverflow.com/a/17347421/1379762

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python:Efficient way to check if dictionary is empty or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312043/pythonefficient-way-to-check-if-dictionary-is-empty-or-not)

Comment: uhhh, `.join(...)` meaning `socket.join(...)`? Is that legal syntax? If so I'd rather like to avoid it, but still interested to know more if there's documentation on it particularly.

duhhh, nevermind... string join :D

Answer (score 1196, accepted):

Empty dictionaries [evaluate to `False`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in Python:

```
>>> dct = {}
>>> bool(dct)
False
>>> not dct
True
>>>
```

Thus, your `isEmpty` function is unnecessary.  All you need to do is:

```
def onMessage(self, socket, message):
    if not self.users:
        socket.send("Nobody is online, please use REGISTER command" \
                    " in order to register into the server")
    else:
        socket.send("ONLINE " + ' ' .join(self.users.keys()))
```

Comment: @Wajih you link is irrelevant: `bool({False: False})`still evaluates to `True`. The link you gave correspond to `any`method, which depends on keys.

Comment: @Wajih what does that mean?

Comment: I feel 'not dict' is not explicit

Comment: agreed, I feel like using the booleans and `not <dict>` is not that clear too

Comment: "your isEmpty function is unnecessary" It makes code easier to understand tho.

Comment: bool(dct) returns False if dct is None as well

Comment: just for clarity, a non-empty dict will return True, i.e. if `dct = {'id': 1}` then `bool(dct)` will return `True`.

Comment: since I can't tag more than one user:

 UlysseBN: `{False: False}` is not an empty dictionary;

 imbatman, cryanbhu, GG.: `not {}` is the clearest, fastest and most pythonic way to check an empty dict;

 Alan: yes, `bool({})`, `bool([])`, `bool(())`, `bool(0)`, `bool("")`, and `bool(None)` all evaluate to `False`. That's why you do identity checks on things which can be `None`: `x is None`, `x is not None`

Answer (score 227):

Here are three ways you can check if dict is empty. I prefer using the first way only though. The other two ways are way too wordy.

```
test_dict = {}

if not test_dict:
    print "Dict is Empty"


if not bool(test_dict):
    print "Dict is Empty"


if len(test_dict) == 0:
    print "Dict is Empty"
```

Comment: Sigh ... everybody likes to be "pythonic" and goes for the least characters to type. First, another criteria is readability. Second, the first test in the answer above is true not only if the dict exists and is empty, but also if test_dict is None. So use this test only when you know that the dict object exists (or when the difference does not matter). The second way also has that behavior. Only the third way barks if test_dict is None.

Comment: @AndreasMaier Exactly my feeling as well. Also, python is dynamically typed. Inside a function it's common to check "if x is non-empty dictionary, then do this; if x is non-empty numpy array, then do that". Then the first code will fail on `if x` when x is numpy array

Comment: @Wajih you link is still irrelevant here... See [why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177439/python-checking-if-a-dictionary-is-empty-doesnt-seem-to-work#comment-71768805)

Comment: Not upvoting this although technically correct due to concerns I share with. @AndreasMaier

Comment: @AndreasMaier and the pythonic way to solve this is to add `if test_dict is not None: print("Dict is None")` at the beginning

Answer (score 36):

```
d = {}
print(len(d.keys()))
```

If the length is zero, it means that the dict is empty.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `len(dict.keys())` is equivalent to `len(dict)`

Comment: @pdpAxis In the value it gives, though I bet the implementation of `dict.__len__` is probably a bit faster. :)

Answer (score 28):

Simple ways to check an empty dict are below:

```
a = {}
```

1. ```
   if a == {}:
     print ('empty dict')
   ```
2. ```
   if not a:
     print ('empty dict')
   ```

Method 1 is more strict, because when `a = None`, method 1 will provide the correct result, but method 2 will give an incorrect result.

Answer (score 9):

A dictionary can be automatically cast to boolean which evaluates to `False` for empty dictionary and `True` for non-empty dictionary.

```
if myDictionary: non_empty_clause()
else: empty_clause()
```

If this looks too idiomatic, you can also test `len(myDictionary)` for zero, or `set(myDictionary.keys())` for an empty set, or simply test for equality with `{}`.

The isEmpty function is not only unnecessary but also your implementation has multiple issues that I can spot prima-facie.

1. The `return False` statement is indented one level too deep. It should be outside the for loop and at the same level as the `for` statement. As a result, your code will process only one, arbitrarily selected key, if a key exists. If a key does not exist, the function will return `None`, which will be cast to boolean False. Ouch! All the empty dictionaries will be classified as false-nagatives.
2. If the dictionary is not empty, then the code will process only one key and return its value cast to boolean. You cannot even assume that the same key is evaluated each time you call it. So there will be false positives.
3. Let us say you correct the indentation of the `return False` statement and bring it outside the `for` loop. Then what you get is the boolean **OR** of all the keys, or `False` if the dictionary empty. Still you will have false positives and false negatives. Do the correction and test against the following dictionary for an evidence.

`myDictionary={0:'zero', '':'Empty string', None:'None value', False:'Boolean False value', ():'Empty tuple'}`

Answer (score 5):

##### 1st Way

```
len(given_dic_obj)
```

It returns 0 if there are no elements.
Else, returns the size of the dictionary.

##### 2nd Way

```
bool(given_dic_object)
```

Returns `False` if the dictionary is empty, else return True.

Comment: You have this the wrong way round - bool(given_dic_object) returns False if the dictionary is empty

Comment: @andy: haven't I mentioned the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use get(). Initially I believed it to only check if key existed.

```
>>> d = { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':{}}
>>> bool(d.get('c'))
False
>>> d['c']['e']=1
>>> bool(d.get('c'))
True
```

What I like with get is that it does not trigger an exception, so it makes it easy to traverse large structures.

Answer (score -9):

use 'any'

```
dict = {}

if any(dict) :

     # true
     # dictionary is not empty 

else :

     # false 
     # dictionary is empty
```

Comment: `any` checks if the dict contains any truthy key, e.g. `any({0: 'something'})` returns `False` even though the dict is not empty

Comment: yeah that to save from both cases , truthy and blank, other wise bool would have given true for truthy case . if you think in general coding purpose .