# Unexpected behavior from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and I am a bit confused with the way Python treats an empty object.

Consider this code piece;

```
a = {}

if a:
    print "a is alive!"
else:
    print "a is NOT alive!"

if not a:
    print "NOT a!"
else:
    print "a!"

if a is None:
    print "a is None!"
else:
    print "a is NOT None!"
```

I get the following output for this code piece.

```
a is NOT alive!
NOT a!
a is NOT None!
```

### Edit::

I am under the assumption that an object initialized by {} is a Valid Object. Why doesn't Python treat it that way? and why do I get diff output for diff If conditions?

### Edit 2::

In C++, when I say

```
 Object obj;
 if (obj){
 }
```

It will enter the IF block if obj is NOT NULL(regardless if it is garbage value or whatever)

But the same thing when I translate to python.

```
a = {} #This is a valid object
if a:
# Doesn't work!
```

Why? and I read Python evaluates {} as False. Why is that?

Comment: The output is correct, what else were you expecting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Checking if a 'Dictionary' is empty doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177439/python-checking-if-a-dictionary-is-empty-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: The output is correct and this is how it's done in Python. Even you said that you check with "If not".

Comment: we don't know *what* to explain. please clarify!

Comment: Downvoted on account that you don't include what you think the expected behaviour is.

Comment: Empty dict is the same as "False", but not the same as None. What did you expect?

Comment: @Rusty yes exactly, why is that so? that's my question!

Comment: explain what you expected to happen.

Comment: @All... I know the output I'm getting, I am asking why diff If conditions are giving diff output.

Comment: because they are different conditions and statements. do you expect the same thing will happen no matter what you type?

Comment: I have edited the question once again.

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600295/what-is-the-meaning-of-operator-bool-const-in-c

Comment: Everything is a valid python object. `False` evaluation has nothing to do with its validity. Show me an invalid python object, I don't think I've ever heard of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing weird in your output.
Let's go step-by-step:

- `a` is dictionary, more specifically a dictionary *object*;
- `a` is a dictionary, but it's empty, so its truth value is `False`

Therefore:

- The first `if`, since `a` is `False`, prints the `else` statement and that's right;
- The second `if`, since `not a` evaluates to `True` because `a` is `False`, prints the `if` part and that's right too.
- Last, but not least `a` is not a `None` object, but a `dict` object, so it's right too that the `else` part is taken and printed.

Comment: <<<<a is a dictionary, but it's empty, so its truth value is False>>>> when I say a={}, does it means that it's not allocated any memory until I add an item to it?

Comment: If you do `a={}` memory is allocated (on my system 280 bytes are allocated); you can check doing `sys.getsizeof(object)`. The truth value of the dictionary is determined from the fact that is empty. It's a pythonic behaviour and it works also on empty strings, lists, sets and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Empy dict/sets/lists etc are evaluated as false. None is its own type, with only one possible value.

https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html Tells you what is evaluated as true and false

Comment: +1. I wanted to edit it in my answer, but you beat me to it, good job!

Comment: saying that they are evaluated as false is misleading. only in *boolean* context.

Comment: The key difference is that you are using `is` None. So not only is an empty dictionary not *equal* to None, it is also not exactly the same object. For the same reason `{} == {}` evaluates as True, but `{} is {}` evaluates False - they are both empty dicts, but they are not the *same* empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid python object, but it is empty, so it is treated as a `False`, the same goes for lists `[]` or numbers `0`. You do have a dict, but it is not a `None` object.

Answer (score 0):

with

```
a = {}
```

you are creating an dictionary object which is not NoneType you can 
check the class of your object with

type(a)

which will give you:

> type dict

```
if not a:
```

will return False if a has already any members and True if a is just and empty list