# How to skip a line of code based on certain condition? python dictionary min

Tags: python, dictionary

in python:

```
dic = {}    #start with an empty list
```

After this line, I did a series of command to add things to the `dic`. But there is also a situation where nothing is added. Then, I need to use the value in the `dic`.

```
a = min(dic, key=dic.get)
```

if there is nothing in the `dic`, it will give me an error:
`ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence` I don't need an output for `a` if `dic` is empty, so I then attempted to use the if statement to get away:

```
if dic == None: 
    pass
else:
    a = min(dic, key=dic.get)
```

but this will still give me the same error. Is there a way to skip this line of code`a = min(dic, key=dic.get)`when `dic = {}`?

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177439/python-checking-if-a-dictionary-is-empty-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: you can use `if dic: a = min(dic, key=dic.get)`

Comment: An empty dictionary is not equal to None.

Comment: In your own words: why do you think a dictionary that is empty should compare equal to `None`? In your own words: how do you write an empty dictionary?

Comment: As a side note, to help you ask better questions in the future: try to be clear in your question title about *what is actually confusing you*. You know how to use `if`; you didn't know why the `if` condition wasn't working as you expected. It should be clear that there is only one possible point of failure: the condition that you're checking. Therefore, you should phrase the question that way - "why does this condition not check that a dictionary is empty?" or something along those lines. When you think more clearly like that, it also helps you find better Internet search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dic` is of the `<class dict>` whereas the `None` object is of the `<class 'Nonetype'>`.
So the given expression `dic == None`will always return `False`.
Instead change it to `dic == {}` or `len(dic) == 0` or simply `dic`.
An empty dictionary will usually evaluate to `False`.

```
if dic: 
 pass
else:
 a = min(dic, key=dic.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the logic to:

```
if len(dic) == 0: 
    pass
else:
    a = min(dic, key=dic.get)
```

You current code skips over the pass block because even if the dict `dic` is empty, it is not `None`, there's a bunch of ways to check emptiness of a dict, personally, I'm a fan of checking the `len` as above but there are other way such as on this [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-dictionary-is-empty/).