# How can I check if the request data is empty in the Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request

I'm trying to write an APIView using the Django REST framework. In the [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) method I want to check if the request data contains anything, because I often get **KeyError**.

I can achieve it using the following code:

```
        if request.data is not None and request.data != {}:
            username = request.data["username"]
```

Is there a better way to write the above code? Especially `request.data != {}`

Comment: You're basically asking how to validate an empty dictionary.
Repeated question answer can be found here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177439/python-checking-if-a-dictionary-is-empty-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Empty dictionaries evaluate to False. So you could simply use `if not` to validate

Answer (score 1):

Since empty dictionaries evaluate to `False`, you could simply use an `if not` operator to validate the data.

As easier approach to your code would be to

```
if not request.data:
   username = request.data["username"]
```

### You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177439/python-checking-if-a-dictionary-is-empty-doesnt-seem-to-work)

---

Alternatively, you could use a serializer to validate the fields. Here is an example on how you can implement this:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

^Assuming that those are your fields. You can change them to your model fields.

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion in Django REST framework is to use a serializer which will validate the fields. Take a look at *[Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)*.